# Error receiving multipart form via WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

how are you?

I created a form in Angular2, which makes a POST request with the form data and upload a file, to a webapi controller.
However I'm having a little problem.

Some users of my system (who access the system outside my company's network) in 20% attempts they submit the form, an error happens (I registered with NLog).
However, if I try to submit the form with the same data and the same files, within the company network, everything works perfect (100% of the attempts).

However the error is intermittent, it happens on average 2 out of 10 requests, and only with users who access the system outside the company network.

And my C # controller:
`public async Task PostFormData() {
        HttpResponseMessage response;

```
    try
    {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            var fileContent = provider.Contents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Headers.ContentType != null &&
                                    (x.Headers.ContentType.MediaType.StartsWith("image/") ||
                                     x.Headers.ContentType.MediaType.Equals("application/pdf")));

            // Function to transform form content in object                         
            var transaction = await FormObject<Product>(provider);

            // Performs data processing, etc...
     }
```

}`

The error happens on the line:

`Await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync (provider);`

The file upload is limited to 5Mb (in Angular2), and in WebConfig I have limited the size of the request and the upload to 30Mb (to leave a certain slack).

The exception that happens is the following:

**StackTrace:**             at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.d__0`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sisprec.Api.Controllers.TransacaoController.d__12.MoveNext()

**InnerException:**         System.Web.HttpException (0x800703E3): The client disconnected.
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpBufferlessInputStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrimPromise`1.Complete(TInstance thisRef, Func`3 endMethod, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.d__8.MoveNext()

And now I do not know what to do.

Thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: Can you deploy the app in debug mode so you can get more info about the error?

Comment: It just sounds like your clients have network problems.

Comment: Same error.
I was deployed in debug mode. Same information, error on the line:


`var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);`



I changed this line to:



`var provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();`



And the same error.